# Oracle (sqlplus is not recognized as an internal or external command)

Tags: windows, oracle, sqlplus

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this problem?

> Sqlplus not recognized as an internal or external command operable
> program or batch file

[image]

Comment: Maybe install sqlplus?

Comment: The result of `echo %ORACLE_HOME%` looks wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a lot of reasons why you can't run SQL*Plus. Let me say a few words, see if anything of that helps.

- if you installed Oracle database (such as XE) on your computer, you'll have SQL*Plus as it comes by default with every Oracle database server installation
- if you don't have Oracle database on your computer, you could have installed Oracle **client** software. There are various options available (full or instant client), and you can pick which part of the client you want to install. For example, SQL Loader, and/or export/import utilities, and/or **SQL*Plus**
- if you already did something of above mentioned things, then directory (which contains SQL*Plus) isn't part of the PATH environment variable. Installer does that for you, but if you modified the PATH and *accidentally* removed the directory from it, then add it. For example, for my 11gXE installation, it is located in

  ```
  C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin
  ```

  - alternatively, if you don't want to add it to PATH (can't think of any reason why not), change current directory to it and then run SQL*Plus:

    ```
    c:\Temp>cd C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin

    C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>sqlplus

    SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Ned Vel 28 11:13:07 2021
    <snip>
    ```
- furthermore, looking at what your screenshot shows, there's no ORACLE_HOME on your computer; there is, on mine:

  ```
  c:\Temp>echo %oracle_home%
  C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server
  ```

I hope it'll get you started.

Comment: I always forget on Windows, but if the DB was just installed, maybe the cmd windows needs to be killed & reopened to pick up the environment.  If Instant Client is chosen (and I'd recommend this if the alternative is the full client), then you can get it from https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html